# What is the meaning of this script field in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

What `parameters.script` means in the following Groovy code:

*example.groovy*

```
class Example {
  def call(Map parameters) {
    def script = parameters.script
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It retrieves a value from a `Map` with the key 'script'. The following are all equivalent

```
def script = parameters.script
script = parameters['script']
script = parameters.get('script')
```

Answer (score 0):

from https://www.timroes.de/2015/06/28/groovy-tutorial-for-java-developers-part3-collections/:
*Beside using brackets you can also use dot notation to access entries*